# Matlab's command counterpart in MMA

Tags: mathematical-optimization

[Matlab has a command](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/math/plot-functions.html) that when is used in `fminsearch` shows the value of the function which we want to minimize and so gives a trend of values calculated for the minimum. It is something like this for a specific problem:

[image]

What is the equivalent command in MMA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

Let's make up a "slow to evaluate" function to minimize:

```
f[x_] := (Pause[0.5]; x^4 - x^2)
```

Some setup:

```
values = {};
Dynamic@ListPlot[values, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

Now run `FindMinimum` and watch the function values decrease in real time:

```
FindMinimum[f[x], {x, 1}, StepMonitor :> AppendTo[values, f[x]]]
```

Comment: Sometimes it crashes. MMA asks me to either disable dynamic updating or wait for it to work.